# FOR type IN on oracle's stored procedures

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, types

I have a type called fatorial_type and a table fatorial created from that type, when executing this code below I got the error "PLS-00302: component 'SET_NUM_FATORIAL' must be declared", and yes that procedure was declared.

```
SET serveroutput ON format wraped;
DECLARE
    fat fatorial_type;
BEGIN  
    FOR fat IN
        (SELECT value(f) FROM fatorial f)
    LOOP
        fat.SET_NUM_FATORIAL(5);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

If I do

```
SELECT value(f) into fat FROM fatorial f
```

thats works, maybe the problem is related with FOR IN that don't work like into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several slightly different syntaxes for looping through resultsets in PL/SQL.  They give us different levels of control over the fetch.  The simplest solution is to not declare a cursor variable and let Oracle resolve things.  But you do need to alias the returned value in the projection.

So, here is a simple type with a method ...

```
create or replace type test_t as object
  ( n number
    , member procedure do_something(x number)
   );
/

create or replace type body test_t as 
  member procedure do_something (x number)
  is
  begin
    dbms_output.put_line(self.n + x);
  end;    
end;
/
```

We create a table on that type ....

```
create table t23 of test_t
/

insert into t23 values (41)
/
insert into t23 values (68)
/
insert into t23 values (71)
/
```

Now let's roll:

```
SQL>
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> begin
  2      for r in ( select value(f) as whatever
  3                 from t23 f )
  4      loop
  5          r.whatever.do_something(1);
  6      end loop;
  7  end;
  8  /
42
69
72

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably confused because you've used "fat" as the name of a variable and the name of the implicit cursor.

try changing the cursor variable to "r"
BEGIN
    FOR r IN
        (SELECT value(f) FROM fatorial f)
    LOOP
        fat.SET_NUM_FATORIAL(5); /* what do you want to do with the value you selected? */
    END LOOP;
END;